# MPJ : object with encapsulation (Serialisation)

Tags: java, serialization, mpi

Here's the context, I'm modifying an evolutionary algorithm to make use of the lab's cluster. So the thing is I need to send our "Individual"  throught the network to be evaluated and get them back.

An Individual look like :

```
public class Individual_Multi extends Individual implements java.io.Serializable, Clonable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    boolean looged, evaluated;
    protected double[][] matrix = new double[9][9];
    protected ArrayList<Reaction> _reactions = new ArraList<Reaction>();

    ... methodes ...
}
```

A Reaction is:

```
public class Reaction implements java.io.Serializable, Clonable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected int leftEnzymeId;
    //5 more
    protected double k_plus;
    //1 more
}
```

(Keep in mind that the number of reactions per individual is not fixed !)

my main:

```
Individual[] P_total = null;
Individual[] P_local = new Individual[n];
if(rank == 0)
{
    P_total = new Individual[n*nproc];
    initialize(P_total); //Populate the array
}

for(int generation = 0 ; generation < 1000 ; generation ++ )
{
   MPI.COM_WOLRD.Scatter(P_total, 0, n, MPI.OBJECT, P_local, 0, n, MPI.OBJECT, 0);

   for(Individual p : P_local)
      p.evaluate();   <--- Error here
   ...
}
```

Evaluate reads the internal of the individual and send it to another class.

EDIT: Method in which the null pointer exception appears

```
public void evaluate()
{
    if (evaluated == true)
        return;
    try 
    {
        _fitness[0] = odesimulation.OdeImplicitSolver_Nicolas.getFitnessValue_2( this.getDescription() );
    }

    _fitness[1] = this._reactions.size();
    evaluated = true;
}
```

getDescription() is just a method calling toString() on all the internals and return the concatenated version.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at runtime.starter.MulticoreStarter$1.run(MulticoreStarter.java:277)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Individual_Multi.evaluate(Individual_Multi.java:752)
    at Evolver.run(Evolver.java:198)
    at Evolver.main(Evolver.java:524)
    ... 6 more
```

(BTW how can I print the rest of the stack?)

When I tried with minimal examples it worked well with a class, but not anymore with encapsulation like here. I would guess that this is the problem, however being new to Java I have no clue concerning the workaround.

As a lazy intern, auto-serialization was the preferred way, but assuming we can pinpoint the problem I am wiling to write serialization methods myself.

Thank you in advance, and have a nice day !
Marc.

EDIT2 : 
I Tried with a simpler example :

```
public class DummyNestedTest implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private int tab;
    public DummyNestedTest(int n)
    {
        tab = n;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(tab);
    }
}
```

The top level class

```
public class DummyTest implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private int[] tab;
    private ArrayList<Float> array;
    private DummyNestedTest nested;

    public DummyTest(int n)
    {
        DummyNestedTest nested = new DummyNestedTest(n); 
        tab = new int[8];
        array = new ArrayList<Float>(8);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < tab.length ; i++)
        {
            tab[i] = n;
            array.add((Float)2.f*n);
        }
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(array.toString());
        System.out.println(tab[0]);
        nested.print();
    }
}
```

And the main :

```
public class MpjTest
{
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        MPI.Init(argv);

        int rk = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
        int np = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Size();
        int n = 20;

        DummyTest[] P = null;
        DummyTest[] Pt = new DummyTest[n/np];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < Pt.length ; i ++)
            Pt[i] = new DummyTest(rk);

        if(rk == 0)
            P = new DummyTest[n];

        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Gather(Pt,0,n/np,MPI.OBJECT,P,0,n/np,MPI.OBJECT,0);

        if(rk == 0)
           for(DummyTest t : P)
            t.print();

        MPI.Finalize();

     }
 }
```

Gives

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at runtime.starter.MulticoreStarter$1.run(MulticoreStarter.java:277)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DummyTest.print(DummyTest.java:25)
    at MpjTest.main(MpjTest.java:33)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Please add the source code of Individual_Multi#evaluate (line 752), a NullPointerException is throw at this location, see what is null.

Comment: Added evaluate and a simpler example, where everything can be seen

Comment: Hello, the error in your example comes from this :

    DummyNestedTest nested = new DummyNestedTest(n); 

You created another reference here, instead of initializing your private `DummyNestedTest nested` field.

Instead you need to do :

    this.nested = new DummyNestedTest(n); 

The fact that this field wasn't initialized threw an error when you tried to call `nested.print();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See saffron's answer !

> Hello, the error in your example comes from this : DummyNestedTest nested = new DummyNestedTest(n); You created another reference here, instead of initializing your private DummyNestedTest nested field. Instead you need to do : this.nested = new DummyNestedTest(n); The fact that this field wasn't initialized threw an error when you tried to call nested.print(); –  Saffron